# How to make real-time multiple line graph?

Tags: android, real-time, mpandroidchart

I want to make real-time multiple linechart using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

It is no problem to make real-time graph using only one data. (following code)

```
private void addEntry(int count) {
    LineData data = mChart.getData();

    if (data != null) {
        LineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

        if (set == null) {
            set = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }

        data.addXValue("");

        data.addEntry(new Entry(getPressure(), set.getEntryCount()), 0);

        data.setDrawValues(false);
        data.setHighlightEnabled(false);

        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // limit the number of visible entries
        mChart.setVisibleXRange(0, count);

        // move to the latest entry
        mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - (count + 1));
    }
}
```

And, it is no problem to make multiple line chart using following code.

```
private void setData(int count, float range) {
    ArrayList<String> xValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
        xValues.add((1 + i) + "");
    }

    ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();

    for (int k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++) {
        ArrayList<Entry> yValues = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
            if (k == 0) {
                yValues.add(new Entry(getSetPressure(), i));
            }
            else if (k == 1) {
                yValues.add(new Entry(getCurrentPressure(), i));
            }
            else {
                yValues.add(new Entry(getSuctionPressure(), i));
            }
        }

        String s;
        String c;
        if (k == 0) {
            s = "Set Pressure";
            c = "#ed1f24";
        }
        else if (k == 1) {
            s = "Current Pressure";
            c = "#004bf6";
        }
        else {
            s = "Suction Pressure";
            c = "#ffba00";
        }

        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(yValues, s);

        set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set.setDrawCubic(false);
        set.setDrawCircles(false);
        set.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor(c));
        set.setCircleSize(8f);
        set.setCircleColorHole(Color.BLACK);
        set.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        set.setLineWidth(3f);
        set.setColor(Color.parseColor(c));
        set.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
        set.setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false);

        dataSets.add(set);
    }

    LineData data = new LineData(xValues, dataSets);

    data.setDrawValues(false);
    data.setHighlightEnabled(false);

    mChart.setData(data);
}
```

However, I do not know how to make multiple real-time linechart graph.

How can I make multiple real-time line chart?

Answer (score 5):

You actually posted the answer to your question in your question.

This line is the key:

```
data.addEntry(... , 0);
```

The `0` at the end specifies the dataset-index where the entry should be inserted.

So what you need to do is simply create as many empty `DataSets` as lines you want to have, and thenn add your `Entries` to whatever `DataSet` you want by using the above mentioned method with the correct index.

[**Here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data) you can find the official wiki entry for dynamic- and realtime-data.

Comment: @Narendra In the OP's first code, there is a line data.addEntry(new Entry(getPressure(), set.getEntryCount()), 0); -----Here, make 0 as 1 in last argument and make dataset called data1. And fill in the arguments with which data to be plotted. Adding second graph is similar to first graph. Only thing is, make the index from 0 to 1.

Comment: @zwarrior yes make uniqueIndex to maintain each graph row.

Comment: @Narendra Yup got it working. Now looking to see how to add current time in X Axis.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void addEntry(int min, int max) {
    data = mChart.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        LineDataSet dataSetGraphA = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        LineDataSet dataSetGraphB = data.getDataSetByIndex(1);
        LineDataSet dataSetGraphC = data.getDataSetByIndex(2);
        LineDataSet dataSetGraphD = data.getDataSetByIndex(3);
        // LineDataSet set1= data.getDataSetByIndex(1);
        // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well
        if (dataSetGraphA == null) {
            dataSetGraphA = setLineDataSet(0);
            data.addDataSet(dataSetGraphA);
        }
        if (dataSetGraphB == null) {
            dataSetGraphB = setLineDataSet(1);
            data.addDataSet(dataSetGraphB);
        }
        if (dataSetGraphC == null) {
            dataSetGraphC = setLineDataSet(2);
            data.addDataSet(dataSetGraphC);
        }
        if (dataSetGraphD == null) {
            dataSetGraphD = setLineDataSet(3);
            data.addDataSet(dataSetGraphD);
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        // yyyy-MM-dd.HH.mm.ss.SS
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        // Now formattedDate have current date/time
        System.out.println("Current time = " + formattedDate);
        Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // add a new x-value first
        data.addXValue(formattedDate);
        data.addEntry(
                new Entry(randomInRange(min, max), dataSetGraphA
                        .getEntryCount()), 0);
        data.addEntry(
                new Entry(randomInRange(min, max), dataSetGraphB
                        .getEntryCount()), 1);
        data.addEntry(
                new Entry(randomInRange(min, max), dataSetGraphC
                        .getEntryCount()), 2);
        data.addEntry(
                new Entry(randomInRange(min, max), dataSetGraphD
                        .getEntryCount()), 3);

        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6);
        mChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(15, AxisDependency.LEFT);
        //
        // // this automatically refreshes the chart (calls invalidate())
        mChart.moveViewTo(data.getXValCount() - 7, 50f, AxisDependency.LEFT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. A wall of code only encourages blind copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
private void addEntry() {

    LineData data = mChart.getData();

    LineDataSet set0 = (LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
    LineDataSet set1 = (LineDataSet) data.getDataSetByIndex(1);

    if (set0 == null || set1 == null) {
        // creation of null
        set0 = createSet();
        set1 = createSet();

        data.addDataSet(set0);
        data.addDataSet(set1);
    }

    data.addXValue("");

    data.addEntry(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 20) + 2f, set0.getEntryCount()), 0);
    data.addEntry(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 20) + 2f, set1.getEntryCount()), 1);

    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6);

    mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 7);            
}
```